# Android SQLite PRIMARY KEY must be unique exception when primary keys are unique

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key

I'm trying to create a table and insert rows using SQLite in an Android application. I need to hard code the primary keys as they will be used in with queries against a database. The primary keys must match the other database.

I create the table with this:

```
CREATE TABLE Properties(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT)
```

Then I have a method that inserts rows based on a query from a database. This is similar to what the query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO Properties (ID, Names) VALUES
(5001, "A Property"),
(4001, "B Property"),
(3001, "C Property")
```

I get an SQLLiteConstraintException with the message "PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)". My primary keys are all unique. I suspect this is happening because the primary keys are not in order. The query I'm doing from the database is ordering by Name, not the primary key.

Interestingly enough, when I extract the SQLite database from my device, it seems to have all of the data.

Comment: it is generally recommended to use _id for the column name in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Interestingly enough, when I extract the SQLite database from my device, it seems to have all of the data.

My guess is that what has happened is that:

- You started off with your app uninstalled
- You installed your app
- You ran your app, invoking this method that inserted three rows in a newly-created database, which succeeded
- You perhaps made some changes to the app
- You ran your app again, invoking this method that tried to insert three rows into the database that already exists with the rows from the prior run, and you fail the uniqueness constraint

It is your job to make sure that either the data you are trying to insert does not exist, or that you do not violate any uniqueness constraints. Since it is unclear what purpose your "method that inserts rows based on a query from a database" is serving, it is difficult to provide you with more concrete advice.

Comment: It seems I was attempting my insert method twice without realizing it when the application first installed.